# Redirect to same URL with Lua on Nginx (openresty setup)

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm looking to modify a request header and redirect it in Lua, I've tried

```
 ngx.redirect("/")
```

and

```
 ngx.exec("/")
```

but I'm getting following error:

```
attempt to call ngx.redirect after sending out the headers
```

Is there a straightforward way to add a header value and redirect it somewhere else in Lua? In the documentation I didn't find any appropriate directive, Is there a way something like this can be done while still using **content_by_lua_file** ?

I'm using openresty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [redirect method documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.redirect):

> Note that this **method call terminates the processing of the current request** and that it must be called before ngx.send_headers or explicit response body outputs by either ngx.print or ngx.say.

So check that or use another request phase handler such as ***rewrite_by_lua***.

As for setting a header, use [ngx.header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.header.HEADER)

E.g:

```
location /testRedirect {
   content_by_lua '
     ngx.header["My-header"]= "foo"
     return ngx.redirect("http://www.google.com")
   ';
}
```

> curl http://127.0.0.1/testRedirect

output:

```html
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: openresty
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 17:34:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
My-header: foo
Location: http://www.google.com

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Most sites will NOT accept custom header coming from a redirect, so consider using a cookie on that case.